# async function in node only runs after response sent

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I have the method:

```
const getTaskOrCategoryRecursive = async (type, id)=>{
    const rslt = await type.findOne.call(type, {_id:id},{}, standardOptions, err=>{
        if(err){
            return({err: err});
        }
    });

    const result = rslt.toObject();
    const tasks = result.tasks;
    const events = result.events;
    result.children = {};
    result.children.tasks = tasks.map(async taskId=>{
        const taskIdString = taskId.toString();
        const rtrn = await getTaskRecursive(taskIdString, err=>{
            if(err){
                return({err: err});
            }
        });
        return rtrn;
    });
    result.children.events = events.map(async eventId=>{
        const eventIdString = eventId.toString();
        await Event.findOne({_id:eventIdString}, standardOptions,err=>{
            if(err){
                return({err: err});
            }
        });
    });
    return result;
}
```

It's called by two methods:

```
const getTaskRecursive = (taskId)=>{
    return getTaskOrCategoryRecursive(Task, taskId)

}
```

and

```
const getCategoryRecursive=(categoryId)=>{
    return getTaskOrCategoryRecursive(Category,categoryId);
};
```

which are called by the function

```
router.get('/:id', verifyToken, async (req,res)=>{
    Branch.getCategoryRecursive(req.params.id)
        .then(
            (cat)=>{
                res.status(200).send(cat);
            },
            (err)=>{
                res.status(500).send(err);
            }
        )
});
```

When I try to run the program, first the `getCategoryRecursive` method runs, then `res.status(200).send(cat);` then the `getTasksRecursive` method which gets the children of the object being sent in the response. `getTasksRecursive` does what it is supposed to, but it's running after the response is sent so the object is empty.

How do I make my asynchronous method run before the response is sent?

UPDATE: Using Aritra Chakraborty's answer, I changed it to the following and it worked.

First I separated the `.map` into a new function:

```
const getAllTasksRecursive = async(taskIds)=>{
    const rtrn = await Promise.all(
        taskIds.map(
            async taskId=>{
                return await getTaskRecursive(taskId.toString(), err=>{if(err){return {err:err}}});
            }
        )
    )
    return rtrn;
}
```

Then I called it in the previous function using:

```
result.children.tasks = await getAllTasksRecursive(tasks);
```

Now I am getting the data back in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because internally a `map` or `foreach` can look something like this:

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function (callback) {
  // this represents our array
  for (let index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
    // We call the callback for each entry
    callback(this[index], index, this)
  }
}
```

It will call the callback alright, but it will not wait for the callback to complete before running the next one.

So, you need one `async foreach` of some sort,

```
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        await callback(array[index], index, array)
    }
}
```

Note, how the callback is being `await`ed.

Your code will have to be something like this:

```
const start = async () => {
  await asyncForEach([1, 2, 3], async (num) => {
    await waitFor(50)
    console.log(num)
  })
  console.log('Done')
}
start()
```

Refer: https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404 This article helped me alot in the past.